# Vertical and horizontal centering inside sideways

Tags: tables, appendices

I am trying to set my tables inside an Appendix. The first table should be on the same page as the section heading. Therefore I am usnig sideways. But I also want to center the table horizontal and also vertical.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\newcommand{\sscr}[1]{\textsubscript{#1}} 

\begin{document}
\section{Appendix}
\begin{sideways}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{Simulation Prognosegüte, Beispiel 1} 
  \label{tab:Sim1} 
\begin{tabular}{clccccc} 
\toprule
  & Methode & MSE\textsubscript{N=30} & MSE\textsubscript{N=50} & 
  MSE\textsubscript{N=100} & MSE\textsubscript{N=200} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & Lasso\textsubscript{CV} & 30.076 (0.566) & 8.833 (0.161) & 3.016 (0.041) & 1.275 (0.017)  \\ 
 & Lasso\textsubscript{1.SE} & 37.392 (0.912) & 10.676 (0.172) & 3.982 (0.057) & 2.018 (0.034)  \\ 
$\rho=0.5$ & Lasso\textsubscript{BIC} & 34.596 (0.712) & 9.305 (0.165) &  3.265 (0.051) & 1.455 (0.023)  \\ 
 & Ridge & 45.295 (0.987) & 13.687 (0.150) & 4.387 (0.046) & 1.846 (0.017)  \\ 
 & OLS & $-$ & 37.295 (0.544) & 6.619 (0.076) & 2.291 (0.027)  \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & Lasso\textsubscript{CV} & 44.993 (0.867) & 14.277 (0.331) & 2.990 (0.055) & 1.120 (0.019) \\ 
 & Lasso\sscr{1.SE} & 57.476 (1.154) & 17.925 (0.432) & 4.215 (0.071) & 1.895 (0.024) \\ 
$\rho=0.9$ & Lasso\sscr{BIC} & 42.786 (0.824) & 9.513 (0.113) & 3.169 (0.033) & 1.168 (0.020)  \\ 
 & Ridge & 40.701 (0.841) & 7.133 (0.097) & 3.428 (0.040) & 1.621 (0.019) \\ 
 & OLS & $-$ & 25.210 (0.525) & 5.779 (0.089) & 1.988 (0.021) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item blabla
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sideways}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some `\hfill` and `\vfill` and an empty `\mbox` to ensure the fill is added:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\newcommand{\sscr}[1]{\textsubscript{#1}} 

\begin{document}
\section{Appendix}
\vfill
\hfill\begin{sideways}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{Simulation Prognosegüte, Beispiel 1} 
  \label{tab:Sim1} 
\begin{tabular}{clccccc} 
\toprule
  & Methode & MSE\textsubscript{N=30} & MSE\textsubscript{N=50} & 
  MSE\textsubscript{N=100} & MSE\textsubscript{N=200} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & Lasso\textsubscript{CV} & 30.076 (0.566) & 8.833 (0.161) & 3.016 (0.041) & 1.275 (0.017)  \\ 
 & Lasso\textsubscript{1.SE} & 37.392 (0.912) & 10.676 (0.172) & 3.982 (0.057) & 2.018 (0.034)  \\ 
$\rho=0.5$ & Lasso\textsubscript{BIC} & 34.596 (0.712) & 9.305 (0.165) &  3.265 (0.051) & 1.455 (0.023)  \\ 
 & Ridge & 45.295 (0.987) & 13.687 (0.150) & 4.387 (0.046) & 1.846 (0.017)  \\ 
 & OLS & $-$ & 37.295 (0.544) & 6.619 (0.076) & 2.291 (0.027)  \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & Lasso\textsubscript{CV} & 44.993 (0.867) & 14.277 (0.331) & 2.990 (0.055) & 1.120 (0.019) \\ 
 & Lasso\sscr{1.SE} & 57.476 (1.154) & 17.925 (0.432) & 4.215 (0.071) & 1.895 (0.024) \\ 
$\rho=0.9$ & Lasso\sscr{BIC} & 42.786 (0.824) & 9.513 (0.113) & 3.169 (0.033) & 1.168 (0.020)  \\ 
 & Ridge & 40.701 (0.841) & 7.133 (0.097) & 3.428 (0.040) & 1.621 (0.019) \\ 
 & OLS & $-$ & 25.210 (0.525) & 5.779 (0.089) & 1.988 (0.021) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item blabla
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sideways}\hfill\mbox{}\vfill

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Just a small question. I've two tables like that, but the code is only working for the first one.

Comment: I suspect the second one doesn't have a heading on the same page. Add a `\mbox{}` at the top, it might help.

Comment: It does ! Thanks, never heard about mbox, thanks !

Comment: @Leo96 its general use is to box small things up so they don't get line or page broken like e.g. you'd use `\mbox{Dr.\@ Watson}` to make sure Dr isn't staying alone at the end of the line/page.

Comment: @Leo96 `\null` could also work, or `\hbox{}` (which is the same as `\null` and almost the same as `\mbox{}`).